# Adding myself back to the sudoers file in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently changed the permissions around for the /var/www/ directory on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Now my user can save to the directory but I get an error whenever I try to run the sudo command stating that my user is not in the sudoers file. I booted up grub to take a look and have tried to run "sudo usermod -G sudo kevin" a few times and get the error cannot lock /etc/passwd/; try again later. Is there any way to re add myself to that group without re-installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your problem stems from the file system being mounted read-only as it is by default in recovery mode. Try remounting the filesystem in read-write mode using

> "mount -o remount,rw /"

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your system is mounted in read/write mode when you're using GRUB? This can be achieved through the `mount -o remount,rw /` command.